# Nested Children in Telerik Treeview with MVC 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, treeview, razor, telerik

I have a fairly simple data model with three tables.. Contracts, Members, Episodes. And am trying to build a telerik treeview to show every entry in the three tables with respect to their relationship in tiers of the tree...

- There are multiple Contracts.
- Each Contract has multiple Members.
- Each Member has Multiple Episodes.

As a note, the telerik demo only shows one section of children.
[Telerik's Online Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/databindingtomodel?theme=vista)

Additionally, their [Drag and Drop](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/draganddrop) demo uses the same tables and simply uses a GetRootEmployee function to pupulate. So I can't find any relevant examples.

### Example:

```
Contract 1's decription
     Member of Contract 1's name    
          Episodeid of Member in Contract 1
     Another Member of Contract 1...
          Episodeid of another Member.
Contract 2's description
```

The **problem** is that I simply cannot get the episodes (third tier) to populate successfully, though the first two work fine. I will post my View, and my controller.

### View

```
 @(
    Html.Telerik().TreeView()
   .Name("myTree")
   .BindTo(Model, mappings =>
     {
       mappings.For<SMTXEFMVCModel.Contract>(binding => binding
         .ItemDataBound((item, contract) =>
           {
             item.Text = contract.Description;
           })
           .Children(contract => contract.Members));
       mappings.For<SMTXEFMVCModel.Member>(binding => binding
         .ItemDataBound((item, member) =>
           {
             item.Text = member.FirstName + " " + member.LastName;
           })  //If I stop here, it populates Contract and Members correctly.
           .Children(member => member.Episodes));
       mappings.For<SMTXEFMVCModel.Episode>(binding => binding
         .ItemDataBound((item, episode) =>
           {
             item.Text = episode.episodeID;
           }));
     })
)
```

### Controller

```
      public ActionResult TreeView()
  {
      var ctx = new SMTXContext();
      var Contracts = ctx.Contracts.ToList();

      return View(Contracts);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was a datatype mixup.

```
item.Text = episode.episodeID;
```

should have been

```
item.Text = episode.episodeID.ToString();
```

then it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

your third mapping seems to be buggy

```
 mappings.For<SMTXEFMVCModel.Member>(binding => binding
         .ItemDataBound((item, episode) =>
           {
             item.Text = episode.episodeID;
           }));
```

shouldn't it define mapping for Episode rather than Member. Furthermore there is no need for

```
var Members = ctx.Members.ToList();
      var Assessments = ctx.Assessments.ToList();
```

when you are not passing these values to view in any way possible like

```
return View(Contracts);
```

Treeview will automatically traverse through Members and Episodes objects through navigational properties of Contract and Member object.

Comment: I must have copied the wrong version. (I've got SMTXEFMVCModel.Episode) in my live version which has the exact same error. I also meant to comment out the lists in the controller, and will edit as appropriate thanks.

Comment: does your data contain episodes?